# upload large file in spring using FileCopyUtils.copy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using **org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils** to upload files in my projects.

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(multipartFile.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream( basePath + "/" + uploadedfile.getFileName()));
```

It use a FileOutputStream for uploading file and for smaller file this work fine, But how I can upload file with 2GB size or higher?

Comment: Have you try to set the property "maxUploadSize" while defining the bean for multipart file?

Comment: @zombie yes, I set "maxUploadSize" property of multipartResolver's Bean to 10000000000 (in bytes) in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: Well doing that for large files like this is not really smart. Use `StreamUtils` and use an input stream instead of a `byte[]` that prevents loading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: @m-deinum I use **`StreamUtils.copy(multipartFile.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream( basePath + "/" + uploadedfile.getFileName()));`**
But this take too long to create target uploaded file with 4GB size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the @m-deinum's comment, I Finally use `org.springframework.util.StreamUtils` to upload large files:

```
StreamUtils.copy(multipartFile.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream( basePath + "/" + uploadedfile.getFileName()));
```

I use an input stream instead of a byte[] for uploading files, also for read (downloading) files I use InputStream:

```
try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(basePath + "/" + fileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do {
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead == buffer.length);

        /* some code for set attributes to httpServletResponse */
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help :

**1st thing we have to check is -**

multipartResolver maxUploadSize: maximum upload size for a single request. That means the total size of all upload files cannot exceed this configured maximum. Default is unlimited (value of -1).

**2nd thing we have to check is -**

which server you are using to run your application?

If it is tomcat then, 
you have to do some configuration in it

Refer : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

maxPostSize

The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

Another Limit is:

maxHttpHeaderSize The maximum size of the request and response HTTP header, specified in bytes. If not specified, this attribute is set to 4096 (4 KB).

You find them in

$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxPostSize="4294967296"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

This will set the maximum file upload size to 4GB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I change maxPostSize in tomcat's server.xml, But the problem still remains;  every file with every size that uploaded, target uploaded file will not greater than 15MB.

Comment: I think http post is allowing  very limited.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/.  OR for larger files transferring you should ftp. or you can chunk the file using applet or something in your client side.